# What is the recommended stable way to update Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, updates, software-center, package-management

I asked this question for the simple fact that software center was trying to **FORCED** 9 software updates that came from a non too familiar source which I believe has been causing Ubuntu to be unstable. I found out that most of the software/packages that were being forced to update manager as updates are software that I do not have on my machine. I made a mistake of installing software/packages before that were pushed through software center and have lived to regret it.

I have to admit that I'm not too familiar with this particular source;

[image]

How can I prevent this from happening in the future?

Comment: Please ask your second question as a new question, this site only works when there's one post per question (I've edited it out for now). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully at Software Sources in System Settings, in "Other Software" tab and disable repositories that contain the software keyword that were force installed, AND PLEASE MORE DETAILS.

Comment: How can I turn off ads on software center? I have disable Ubuntu Wine, but not sure if this is the source. I've just tried refreshing updates to see if the packages are there, but could not find any besides I do not have enough creds to post images.

Comment: please post the name of updates that were installed

Comment: Unfortunately i can't remember exactly, but I think looking at the update manager at the time I saw instant messenger, something to do with email tracker, bitTorrent transmission and security.

Comment: How can I post content from update manager?